# I need help for merging values in object array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with one project , I have the data comes to me as Object Array and I need to combine the same keys in one key and make the value as an array of strings.

here is the data I have :

```
 inputArray = [
    {
      colors: 'Red',
      size: 'Small'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Blue',
      size: 'Large'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Red',
      size: 'Large'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Pink',
      size: 'X-Large'
    }
  ]
```

and here is the required output :

```
 outputArray = {
    colors: ['Red','Blue','Pink'],
    size: ['Large','X-large','Small']
  }
```

Comment: Please give us more details on what you need help with, especially samples of what you've tried and where you've gone wrong. As it stands this is a code request, not a question.

Comment: inputArray = [
    { color: 'Red', size: 'small', brand: 'AVC' },
    { matrial: 'silk', size: 'large', print: 'logo' },
    { color: 'black', size: 'small', material: 'cotton' },
    { color: 'Blue', brand: 'ABC', shaded: '50%' }
  ];

  output = {
    color: ['Red', 'black', 'Blue'],
    matrial: ['silk', 'cotton'],
    size: ['small', 'large'],
    brand: ['ABC', 'AVC'],
    print: ['logo'],
    shaded: ['50%']
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a basic one...

```js
const inputArray = 
  [ { colors: 'Red',  size: 'Small'  } 
  , { colors: 'Blue', size: 'Large'  } 
  , { colors: 'Red',  size: 'Large'  } 
  , { colors: 'Pink', size: 'X-Large'} 
  ];
outputArray = inputArray.reduce((a,c)=>
  {
  if (!a.colors.includes(c.colors) )  a.colors.push( c.colors);
  if (!a.size.includes(c.size) )      a.size.push( c.size);
  return a
  }
  ,{ colors:[], size:[]})
  ;
console.log (outputArray )
```

**[edit]** if you do not know the variety of entry keys, you can use:

```js
inputArray = 
  [ { colors: 'Red',  size: 'Small'  } 
  , { colors: 'Blue', size: 'Large'  } 
  , { colors: 'Red',  size: 'Large'  } 
  , { colors: 'Pink', size: 'X-Large', truc: 'bidule' } 
  ];
outputArray = inputArray.reduce((a,c)=>
  {
  for (let key in c)
    {
    if (!a[key]) a[key] = []
    if (!a[key].includes(c.colors) )  a[key].push( c[key])
    }
  return a
  } ,{})
  ;
console.log (outputArray)
```

Comment: But actually the array key is varied from respond to others not every time will be colors and sizes may change for other keys ...

Comment: I am really sorry ... I am trying to make the question more clearer but maybe I can't ,, thank you anyway ...

Comment: @MohamedMaher  I have added a second answer that could be more on your question?

Comment: It works but there is an error comes here ...
 if (!a[key].includes(c.colors) )  a[key].push( c[key])

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple dictionary structure to do this. And verify if every element already exists before adding it to array.

```
const outputArray = {
  colors: [],
  size: [],
};

for (elem of inputArray) {
  if (!outputArray['colors'].includes(elem.colors)) {
    outputArray['colors'].push(elem.colors);
  }

  if (!outputArray['size'].includes(elem.size)) {
    outputArray['size'].push(elem.size);
  }
}
```

which will give

```
{
   colors: [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Pink' ],
   size: [ 'Small', 'Large', 'X-Large' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
let inputArray = [
    {
      colors: 'Red',
      size: 'Small'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Blue',
      size: 'Large'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Red',
      size: 'Large'
    },
    {
      colors: 'Pink',
      size: 'X-Large'
    }
  ]
let outputArray = [{colors: [], size: []}]
for (let i = 0; i<inputArray.length; i++){
  outputArray[0].colors.push(inputArray[i].colors)
  outputArray[0].size.push(inputArray[i].size)
}
console.log(outputArray)
```

Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

While  this is not logically much different from the second part of the answer by Mister Jojo, it does the same thing without any mutations, in perhaps a more functional manner:

```js
const gather = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (a, x) => Object .entries (x) .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: (a[k] || []).concat(v)}), a),
    {}
  )


const inputArray = [{ colors: 'Red',  size: 'Small'}, {colors: 'Blue', size: 'Large'}, {colors: 'Red',  size: 'Large'}, {colors: 'Pink', size: 'X-Large'}]

console .log (gather (inputArray))
```

It is likely less performant than that version, for reasons [described by Rich Snapp](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern), but in practice I haven't seen this being a real issue.